# iPhone Image Gallery Like App Store

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, image-gallery

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to implement a image gallery like the one that the App Store uses for screen shots of apps? I am trying to get images in a horizontal gallery so that the user can flick through them. The app store nicely snaps to each image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the UIScrollView API [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html). There is a property 'pagingEnabled' that should help you out.

Answer (score 5):

If you want an "App Store screenshot"-like experience, check out [this post by Alexander Repty](http://blog.proculo.de/archives/180-Paging-enabled-UIScrollView-With-Previews.html). I've been looking at doing something similar, and UIScrollView's pagingEnabled functionality definitely won't get you there by itself.

Comment: Thanks for the link! goatlinks just beat you to the answer. I appreciate it.

Comment: Well, goatlinks' link just goes to the documentation for UIScrollView. If you want an "App Store screenshot"-like experience, the page I linked to is more specific to that and should be more helpful - pagingEnabled won't get you there by itself. But no problem. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check out Three20.  http://github.com/facebook/three20/

Comment: Very cool, but not exactly what I was looking for. Thanks though.